# Why dialogflow phone gateway not available in India?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I was trying to use Dialogflow phone gateway but it is only showing 
Country Code US and not India.

Is there any solution to get Indian phone number?

Comment: you can use twilio and call forwarding

Comment: call forwarding in dialogflow or twilio ?

Comment: call forwarding can be done both side, twilio and dialogflow

Comment: How to do it in dialogflow?

Comment: But call forwarding is only supported in US and not in India

Comment: twilio supports both